# 2014 Macbook Air performance with Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, macbook

I read in a meta post that this would be the best place to ask a computer / hardware question, so I sure hope I'm not making a mistake posting this.

I'm looking for a nice, portable laptop for college (going into Software Engineering). The Macbook Air is perfect for what I'm looking for, but I would definitely want to run Windows 8.1 on it.

My question is this: will the Macbook Air perform properly with windows 8? Would I be better off with a native Windows laptop?

If this is not a proper question to ask on SU, I apologize.

Comment: Any [`x86`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) computer that Apple sells today has the capability to run any 64-bit operating system that exists today including the 64-bit version of *Windows 8.1*

Comment: This is asked well, but I think it still boils down to opinion. Yes it'll run it fine, and perform "properly". Would you be better off with a native Windows laptop if your intention is to run Windows? Then yes, _IMO,_ you'd be "better off" with a Windows-centric notebook.  For the cash you would spend on a Macbook Air, you can get a similarly spec'ed out Toshiba Tecra Z-series or alike, and it will it come with Windows 8. Not quite as stylish, but it comes with all the ports, and will be considerably more serviceable if it breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will definitely perform properly with Windows 8.1, but if you plan to run it exclusively, you need to consider this:

- A Windows 8.1 license costs $120 - usually it's included in the price of Windows laptops, but not in Apple laptops. Otherwise if you want to go Pro (hyper-v virtualization, remote desktop), the price is $200.
- Keys on keyboard. I feel weird when I'm using an Apple keyboard on a Windows system due to the ctrl-alt-win keys positions.
- Price. If you don't need to run OSX, you're paying a $400 premium just for the design. There are many ultrabooks that can have the same speed/battery life.

Comment: I appreciate all your answers. Thanks for the help!